# How to use the "symlinks without elevation" feature from the windows 10 Creators Update?

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link

I have installed the Creators Update for Windows 10 and enabled Developer mode.

I can create symlinks using cmd with the command mklink, but my main use of symlinks comes from softwares such as Composer, when I run `composer install`, it gives the error: Unable to create symlink due to error code 1314: 'A required privilege is not held by the client'. Do you have the required Administrator-rights?

I thought they made this options exactly for cases like this (They mentioned Git), what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, the symlink update is in the "Creators Update"

Answer (score 1):

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/

> **How to use Symlinks**
>
> Symlinks are created either using the mklink command or the
>   CreateSymbolicLink API
>
> **mklink**
>
> There is no change in how to call mklink.  For users who have
>   Developer Mode enabled, the mklink command will now successfully
>   create a symlink if the user is not running as an administrator.
>
> **CreateSymbolicLink**
>
> To enable the new behavior when using the `CreateSymbolicLink` API,
>   there is an additional `dwFlags` option you will need to set
>   `SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_ALLOW_UNPRIVILEGED_CREATE`

Therefore, if the software you are using is using the `CreateSymbolicLink` API, then they will need to update their calls to specify the new flag.